# clarification about gdb function format

Tags: c++, gdb

What does this kind of gdb output mean

```
#0  0x0000000000401782 in std::__fill_n_a<long long __vector(4)*, unsigned long, long long __vector(4)> (__first=0x604010, __n=1, __value=...)
```

What exactly does `__value=...` mean?

Comment: Read about [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). In short, there's more to show but it's omitted.

Comment: Can I instruct gdb to give me all output?

Answer (score 1):

From this [documentation link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html):

```
The value of parameter data in frame 1 has been replaced by ….
By default, GDB prints the value of a parameter only if it is a scalar
(integer, pointer, enumeration, etc). See command set print frame-arguments
in Print Settings for more details on how to configure the way function
parameter values are printed.
```

You want: `set print frame-arguments all`